# Trying to track cache behaviour using JFR when testing Apache Ignite with YCSB

Tags: java, ignite, jfr, ycsb

I am testing Apache Ignite version 2.16.0 using YCSB to send 100K inputs of integers. I want to use JFR to track when cache operations happen. I added the following JFR events in `ignite/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java`

```
@Name("org.apache.ignite.CacheGet")
@Label("Cache Get Operation")
class CacheGetEvent extends Event {
    @Label("Key")
    String key;

    @Label("Operation Success")
    boolean success;
}

@Name("org.apache.ignite.CachePut")
@Label("Cache Put Operation")
class CachePutEvent extends Event {
    @Label("Key")
    String key;

    @Label("Operation Success")
    boolean success;
}

@Name("org.apache.ignite.CacheRemove")
@Label("Cache Remove Operation")
class CacheRemoveEvent extends Event {
    @Label("Key")
    String key;

    @Label("Operation Success")
    boolean success;
}
```

I also use them in the `get()`, `put()` and `remove()` functions in the same file:

```
    @Override public V get(K key) {
        CacheGetEvent event = new CacheGetEvent();
        event.key = key.toString(); // Assuming key.toString() provides a meaningful representation
        event.begin();

        IgniteInternalCache<K, V> delegate = getDelegateSafe();
    
        try {
            V result;
            if (isAsync()) {
                setFuture(delegate.getAsync(key));
                result = null;
            }
            else {
                result = delegate.get(key);
            }
            event.success = true; // Operation succeeded
            return result;
        }
        catch (IgniteCheckedException | IgniteException e) {
            event.success = false; // Operation failed
            throw cacheException(e);
        }
        finally {
            event.commit(); // Commit the JFR event regardless of the outcome
        }
    }

    @Override public void put(K key, V val) {
        CachePutEvent event = new CachePutEvent();
        event.key = key.toString(); // Capture the key involved in the operation
        event.begin();

        IgniteInternalCache<K, V> delegate = getDelegateSafe();
    
        try {
            if (isAsync())
                setFuture(putAsync0(key, val));
            else
                delegate.put(key, val);
            
            event.success = true; // Mark the operation as successful
        }
        catch (IgniteCheckedException | IgniteException e) {
            event.success = false; // Mark the operation as failed
            throw cacheException(e);
        }
        finally {
            event.commit(); // Commit the JFR event regardless of the outcome
        }
    }

    @Override public boolean remove(K key) {
        CacheRemoveEvent event = new CacheRemoveEvent();
        event.key = key.toString(); // Capture the key involved in the operation
        event.begin();

        IgniteInternalCache<K, V> delegate = getDelegateSafe();
        boolean result;
    
        try {
            if (isAsync()) {
                setFuture(delegate.removeAsync(key));
                result = false; // Async operation, actual result unknown here
            }
            else {
                result = delegate.remove(key); // Synchronous operation, result known
            }
            event.success = true; // Assuming success if no exception
        }
        catch (IgniteCheckedException | IgniteException e) {
            event.success = false; // Mark the operation as failed
            throw cacheException(e);
        }
        finally {
            event.commit(); // Commit the JFR event regardless of the outcome
        }
    
        return result;
    }
```

I build Ignite using `mvn` then I run it using the following script:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk use java 17.0.10-librca

IGNITE=/home/sameer/thesis/ignite
#/home/sameer/thesis/ignite

# Define the directory for storing JFR recordings
JFR_DIR=data/jfr
mkdir -p "$JFR_DIR" # Ensure the JFR directory exists

# Define the filename for the JFR recording
JFR_FILE="$JFR_DIR/ignite_recording.jfr"

# Ensure directories for Ignite data exist
mkdir -p /data/dbignite
mkdir -p /data/walignite
mkdir -p /data/walarchignite

# Include JFR options in the JVM options
export JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=$JFR_FILE,dumponexit=true"

# Start Ignite with the specified XML configuration
"$IGNITE"/bin/ignite.sh ignite01.xml
```

However, whenever I convert the .jfr recording that gets produced to a json using `jfr print --json --events "*" data/jfr/ignite_recording.jfr > data/jfr/ignite_recording.json`, none of the custom cache events are present. Do I need to add the custom JFR events to a different file in the Ignite source code?

Comment: FWIW, the JFR events look correct. In JDK 11+, the option dumponexit=true is not needed when you specify a filename and -XX:+FlightRecorder is a NOP and can be dropped.  I don't know how IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java works, but I would put in a null guard for key.toString().

Answer (score 0):

It's just a theory, I haven't tried it, but I have a suspicion that the events in question are not even being fired. In that case the cache events should be explicitly enabled in the `IgniteConfiguration` bean. The [doc](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/events/listening-to-events#enabling-events) says how to achieve that.